# creating bas relief from 2d vector curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, sculpting, displacement

I am trying to create bas relief type models from curves created from an svg. I filled then extruded the curve, now I want sculpt and/or bevel the parts using the curves as a guide.

For example, for the fingers, can the preexisting lines be used as guides?

I am wondering how to best go about this. Or if anyone has tips for creating bas relief from 2D vector curves. I have tried creating gradients in illustrator and importing them as displacement maps but they suffer from jagged edges (I am cnc cutting these)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think it would really help if you showed us a sample of the curves you intend to use as maps.. or at least a representative test.

Comment: Maybe you should try with displacement maps if you have a greyscale but you don't give enough elements, maybe share your file or your image or your svg

Comment: file added! thank you so much!

Comment: Master of bas relief in blender is Vilem Duha (founder of BlenderKit) ... check his work or addon he wrote for such purpose https://blenderartists.org/t/bas-relief-addon/593226 he would be pleased by your interest i guess, I remember his patience for bas-relief on cnc arts :)

Comment: Just a note ussually people use 3D model for bas relief ... any specific reason you start from SVG?

Comment: Cool link, I'm wondering if BlenderCAM still works with newer versions of Blender since the website says it is just for archive purposes? The reason for starting with SVG is that I already have vectors / drawing I would like to use. :)

Comment: Even page say to blender 3.5.1 https://github.com/vilemduha/blendercam I followed instructions for 3.2 installed all dependencies on Mac, but i can't see BlenderCAM between render engines listed ... detailed instructions you can find under Wiki label

Answer (score 0):

It is quite dificult for me to imagine to easily sculpt relief based on vector shape (probably show some reference of desired result, probably you aim to something stylized (not realistic).

In meantime  consider to find rigged human model, make a pose and generate relief from 3D.

### 3D (until someone 2D :)

In this simple test ...
Render Depth pass with this node tree Compositor that partly helps to shrink depth but avoid some detail flattening.

[image]
[image]

... and as suggested in moonboots's comment use this height map render as a texture for displacement modifier. Here used with Smooth modifier (because even rendered as EXR 32 bit it wasnt completaly smooth

[image]

[image]

And yes ... it is very dense mesh.

Alternatively [this looks promissing](https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/lgL3/bas-relief-generator-2-0-for-blender-painter) ... render Normal map is easy and if you find convetor to Height map ... [here is one addon](https://github.com/HugoTini/DeepBump), but I have an issue install dependencies.